# Underline first n characters of words

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to underline the first few characters of words in a link, similar to how CSS first-letter works but with a variable number of letters. Alternatively, underlining the first half of a word's letters could be useful. Any way to do this relatively simply with HTML, CSS or Javascript?

(I'm no developer, and am open to all and any suggestions to pass on to the development team ;)

Comment: Vanilla JS or will a lib work like jQuery/mooTools?

Comment: Why isn't the "development team" working on it?

Comment: It's an interaction concept I wanted to assess before taking up valuable developer time. (not implying your time isn't valuable...)

Comment: Just be aware it's an unusual statement to make, but not necessarily an issue related to the underlying question.

Comment: See my answer @RussBB i think that i got what you want

Answer (score 9):

```
<a href="#" class="underline">This is text.</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="underline">More text.</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="">No underline.</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="underline">Underline me.</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="">Nada here though.</a><br/>

a,
a.underline {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.underline span {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

var links = document.links;
var chars = 3;

for (var i = 0, total = links.length; i < total; i++) {
    if (links[i].className.indexOf('underline') > -1) {
        var text = links[i].innerHTML;
        text = '<span>' +
            text.substring(0, chars) +
            '</span>' +
            text.substring(chars);
        links[i].innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/

**EDIT:** Words.

```
var links = document.links;
var chars = 3;

for (var i = 0, total = links.length; i < total; i++) {
    if (links[i].className.indexOf('underline') > -1) {
        var text = links[i].innerHTML.split(' ');
        for (var p = 0, words = text.length; p < words; p++) {   
            text[p] = '<span>' +
                text[p].substring(0, chars) +
                '</span>' +
                text[p].substring(chars);
        }
        links[i].innerHTML = text.join(' ');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/1/

**EDIT**: As a function.

```
var links = document.links;
var chars = 2;

for (var i = 0, total = links.length; i < total; i++) {
    if (links[i].className.indexOf('underline') > -1) {
        setUnderline(links[i], chars);
    }
}

function setUnderline(link, chars) {
    var text = link.innerHTML.split(' ');
    for (var p = 0, words = text.length; p < words; p++) {   
        text[p] = '<span>' +
            text[p].substring(0, chars) +
            '</span>' +
            text[p].substring(chars);
    }
    link.innerHTML = text.join(' ');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/2/

Comment: Thanks Jared, that's close, but actually I was hoping for a way to underline the first n letters in each word of the words in a link.

Comment: See edit. Note a more complete solution will have to be designed around the specs; for a proof of concept, this should work. It's not necessarily the most complex request, depending on the actual HTML it has to work with. jQuery would make it more straight-forward as well.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. So it's doable, which is what I was after. I'll inquire about jQuery as you recommend.

Comment: This is the same thing in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/hMEHB/4/ The selection part is the simplification mostly. Note, this example will actually strip out markup from within the `a` tag using `$.text()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put `&#818;` after any word and it becomes underlined, its a HTML Code.

`<input type=button value=S&#818;end>`

It becomes:

S̲end

But you can create a JavaScript function to do it for you, see:

```
function underlineWord(pos,str){
  str = str.substring(0,pos) + str[pos] + "&#818;" + str.substring(pos+1,str.length);
  return str;
}
```

This way, if you execute:

```
underlineWord(0,"string");
```

You will have:

s̲tring

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to replace the first N letters in a link or the first N letters of each word in a link. If the latter, try replacing the regex

```
new RegExp("\b\w{1," + N + "}", "g")
```

with an appropriate replacement such as

```
function(a) { return "<u>" + a + "</u>"; }
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AZpG7/