# Showing lines underneath input

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a simple verification (no backend) for my app.

It will contain an input that only can take up to four digits and every time a user inputs one digit a line underneath the number will appear.

Because I'm really bad at explaining stuff here's an image of what I want to achieve:
[image]

As you can see the input will take up to four digits. And every time a new number has been inserted a line will appear.

**Some code snippets**

```html
<ion-slide style="color: black">
  <div class="row row-white">
    <div class="col col-white">
      <h4 style="margin-top:100px;">Martin Nordström</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-white">
    <div class="col col-white">
      <p style="margin-bottom:60px">0732649635</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-white">
    <div class="col col-white">
      <input type="number">
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

I guess I could add a `$watch` to see when a value has been changed and therefore update the CSS class with jQuery?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648867/underline-first-n-characters-of-words

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a repeating linear gradient. I did not come up with the idea. The source I got the code from is below the snippet.

The `ch` unit applies a size relative to width of the "0" (zero), so it is important to keep the font family the same, because each character has the same width and height.

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 6ch;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, dimgrey 0, dimgrey 1ch, transparent 0, transparent 1.5ch) 0 100%/ 5.5ch 2px no-repeat;
  font: 5ch droid sans mono, consolas, monospace;
  letter-spacing: 0.5ch;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1346">
```

**Source:** https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/mRrPwB